# Why isn't prerender.io service reached with this configuration?

Tags: html, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, prerender

I own an Angular app and an Apache server.

I set `<meta name="fragment" content="!" />` on the `<head>` part and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

In my `.htaccess` file on the Apache server, I added this part:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "My_Token"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

            # Don't rewrite files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]

            <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
                  RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://example.com/$2 [P,L]
           </IfModule>
            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, when I run the following command:
`curl http://example.com?_escaped_fragment_=`
I don't get the prerendered file.

Sounds that Prerender's service is not triggered at all.

Did I miss some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You might be serving your index from here:

```
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Can you try moving the prerender config higher than that section?

Comment: Surely an issue regarding permission set in the htaccess. I check. It's the `P` flag in the sequence `[P,L]` that causes the 403 error. Is it a known issue?

Comment: Related question I've just asked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224988/my-server-doesnt-allow-a-proxy-to-service-prerender-io#35224988